# Java Stream collectors: how to create total with counting

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of objects of class `Result` defined as:

```java
class Result {
    String code;
    String description;
    Duration value;
}
```

and these two classes:

```java
class Product {
    String code;
    String description;
}
```

---

```java
class Total {
    Duration total;
    long count;
}
```

Given the `List<Result>` I have to generate a `Map<Product, Total>` where in total I have the sum of every value in `Result` that has the same `code` and `description` (this is key) and as count how many result with this key is present in the list of results.

For creating the total sum I consider to use `plus(Duration)` of `Duration`.

How can I do this?
Thanks for the help.

###### UPDATE:

From the comments hints I was able to do this:
(Can someone tell me if it can be correct?)

```java
Map <Product, Total> map = results.stream()
                                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> new Product(p.getCode(), p.getDescription()),
    Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), list -> {
        Duration total = list.stream().map(Result::getValue).reduce(Duration.ZERO, Duration::plus);
        long count = list.size();
        return new Total(total, count);
    })));
```

Comment: I think with `groupingBy` you can solve your task. Check the article [Guide to Java 8 groupingBy](https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector#10-aggregating-multiple-attributes-of-a-grouped-result)

Comment: Also consider stream.reduce in addition to groupingBy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is working and formally correct, but it is wasteful to collect all elements into `List`s, just to perform another Reduction afterwards. Perform the Reduction in the first place:

```java
Map<Product, Total> map = results.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> new Product(r.getCode(), r.getDescription()),
        Collectors.teeing(
            Collectors.reducing(Duration.ZERO, Result::getValue, Duration::plus),
            Collectors.counting(),
            Total::new)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own `Collector`:

```java
public static Map<Product, Total> calc(List<Result> results) {
    return results.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            result -> new Product(result.getCode(), result.getDescription()),
            Collectors.mapping(Result::getValue, new Collector<Duration, Total, Total>() {
                @Override
                public Supplier<Total> supplier() {
                    return () -> new Total(Duration.ZERO, 0);
                }

                @Override
                public BiConsumer<Total, Duration> accumulator() {
                    return (total, duration) -> {
                        total.setTotal(total.getTotal().plus(duration));
                        total.setCount(total.getCount() + 1);
                    };
                }

                @Override
                public BinaryOperator<Total> combiner() {
                    return (one, two) -> new Total(one.getTotal().plus(two.getTotal()),
                                                   one.getCount() + two.getCount());
                }

                @Override
                public Function<Total, Total> finisher() {
                    return Function.identity();
                }

                @Override
                public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
                    return Set.of(Characteristics.UNORDERED);
                }
            })));
}
```

Comment: Seems overkill, no?

Comment: Yep. I prefer not using Stream in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way.

```
        Map<Product, Total> ans = results.stream().collect(groupingBy(r -> new Product(r.code, r.description), collectingAndThen(toList(), list -> {
        long count = list.size();
        Duration total = list.stream().map(r -> r.value).reduce((o1, o2) -> o1.plus(o2)).get();
        return new Total(total, count);
    })));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
Map<Product, Total> result = resultList.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    r -> new Product(r.getCode(), r.getDescription()),
    Collectors.reducing(
        new Total(Duration.ZERO, 0),
        r -> new Total(r.getDuration(), 1),
        (t1, t2) -> new Total(t1.getDuration().plus(t2.getDuration()), t1.getCount() + t2.getCount())
    )
));
```